# DynamoDB Batch Update Attributes with Unique Update and Condition Expressions

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to update multiple attributes in a single DynamoDB item with unique update and conditional expressions for each attribute in a single request? Similar to how an SQL statement might use a `CASE` statement

```sql
UPDATE some_table
  SET column1 = CASE WHEN column1 == 0 THEN newValue1 ELSE column1,
  SET column2 = CASE WHEN column2 == 0 THEN newValue2 ELSE column2,
...
```

Take an example item with attributes `att1` and `att2`.

I would like to be able to update attribute `att1` if `att1 < value.att1`, where `value` is just new data. At the same time, I'd like to update `att2` under the same conditions (`att2 < value.att2`), but not have this update depend on the value of `att1` or it's conditional.

```scala
val value = newAttributeData

new UpdateItemRequest()
  .withUpdateExpression("SET att1 = :att1Update")
  .withConditionExpression("att1 < :att1Update")
  .withExpressionAttributeValues(
    Map(":att1Update" -> new AttributeValue(value.att1)))
```

Additionally, I'd like to also update the following:

```
new UpdateItemRequest()
  .withUpdateExpression("SET att2 = :att2Update")
  .withConditionExpression("att2 < :att2Update")
  .withExpressionAttributeValues(
    Map(":att2Update" -> new AttributeValue(value.att2)))
```

I can't combine these conditional statements into a single statement, because if one of them is true, both values will get updated.

These requests work fine on their own, but I can't seem to combine these into a single request. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you able to find a solution for this issue, I have similar usecase

Comment: Haven't looked at this in years and I don't recall if I stumbled upon a solution, apologies